# How to efficiently update a Blazor server page in real-time using SignalR

Tags: signalr, blazor-server-side

I am building a Blazor server app which needs to send real time updates to users.

By using SignalR I am able to send updates to groups of clients, but my question is how the update should be handled in an eneficient way:

- Send the entire updated object using SignalR?
- Perform a database call to retrieve again the updated object (this means a call for each group member)?

Comment: Did you already resolve your issue? I would suggest some example code for your question...